# How to make Flashdevelop errors appear in Results Panel?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, error-handling, flashdevelop

I am using Flashdevelop to build an Actionscript 3.0 game. It was originally a FlashIDE project but I decided to migrate the project to FlashDevelop. I also changed some asset and property names, as a result there were a lot of syntax error. The errors keep coming out in the Output Panel instead of Results Panel (is that normal) when compiled. I know that when I click errors in the Results Panel it will open and point the error in the Code Panel. I can't do that with errors in the Output Panel (I assume its normal). Is there something I can do to make the errors clickable ?

Even a simple error like this doesnt come out in the Results panel:

```
Loading configuration file H:\04 Noveline\03 GD\GD03\Folder (aaaa)\TEST\obj\MeccatomedinaConfig.xml
H:\FD(1)\TEST\src\Game.as(75): col: 3 Error: Access of undefined property sssss.
sssss
^
Build halted with errors (fcsh).
(fcsh)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

afaik it's impossible to make output panel clickable. but you can press F10 to open program settings dialog and check if your results panel is disabled. and also disable output panel if it's really annoying)

Comment: Thanks found the program settings regarding Results Panel and Output Panel but both are not disabled. I have noticed that my other projects are okay, just this one that doesnt show up anything on the Results Panel. Just to make sure its a setting problem, I have copied everything to newly created project and the errors comeout at the Result Panel :) should be able to continue my migration. However I am still curious what could be the problem with the .proj is was working on. Is there any other settings to control output/error handling that could cause the errors not to appear in Result Panel?

Comment: did you restart FlashDevelop and/or your computer?

Comment: Yup I did. BTW I found out roughly why the errors didnt comeout on the Results Panel. It was because of the folder the project was in. Apparently Folder names must not contain "(" and ")" brackets. Maybe its a Flashdevelop bug? removing the brackets solved the problem :)

Comment: i'm not sure if brackects are allowed in package paths :)

Comment: @Stucko renaming the folder name (removing spaces) was actually a solution to my problem as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**The errors should appear in the results panel and the output panel.** Make sure the results panel is open.

Comment: The Results Panel is open. but still the error doesn't come out there

Comment: This seems to be a problem with the ASC2.0 compiler, having that problem even with the latest FD 4.6.0.18 release.

Comment: I've the same problem with the latest version (4.6.0.18), it was working before I updated FD.

Comment: ah... seems to be fixed in version 4.6.1

Answer (score 0):

Remove parentheses from project path to workaround the issue.
(As Stucko & Markus von Broady wrote in comments.)

This issue is still around for FlashDevelop 5.1.1.1.
I have logged the issue here for ref:
https://github.com/fdorg/flashdevelop/issues/1676